# Complex modulus partial derivative with respect to complex number

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Which of the following is correct (considering $z = a+ib$):

1) Considering that $z$ and $z^*$ are independent $\frac{\partial |z|^2}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial (zz^*)}{\partial z} = z^*$

2)
$\frac{\partial |z|^2}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial (a^2+b^2)}{\partial (a+ib)} = \frac{\partial (a^2+b^2)}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial (a+ib)} + \frac{\partial (a^2+b^2)}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial (a+ib)}  = 2a +2b\frac{1}{i} = 2 (a-ib) = 2 z^*$

Comment: $z^*$ is the complex conjugate  of $z$ and thus depends on $z$ ...

Comment: And what is your definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in case the function is not complex differentiable?

Comment: @user251257 $z^*$ and $z$ are considered independent in literature and all over the internet (do a quick search) and $\partial z / \partial z^*$ is 0. And is the current function not complex differentiable?

Comment: ah have you meant that $z$ and $z^*$ are independent from other variables? Okay, my bad. But that's not important here. Notice that $|z|^2$ is not everywhere complex differentiable.

Comment: no, I meant they're independent from each other, it is proved by $\partial z / \partial z^*=0$. Also I just want to know which of the two answers is "more" correct, the second one, right?

Comment: what is the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z^*}$? There is only one correct answer (at $z\ne 0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) is correct.

For 2), the problem is that $\frac{\partial a}{\partial (a+ib)} = 1/2 $ instead of 1:
$$a = \frac{(a+ib) + (a-ib)}{2}$$
which leads to 
$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial (a+ib)} = 1/2$$
Then the approach in 2) leads to the same conclusion as in 1).